What's the most accurate translation for "Comic Convention"?
Comic Conventions, or Cosplay, Anime, Manga Conventions are popular all around the globe. How would native Italians name them?
I found many possibilities:

fiera del fumetto
manga convention
evento cosplay
fiera cosplay


They're usually officially called "fiera del fumetto" from the organizers.
"Evento cosplay" or "fiera cosplay" can still be correct, even tho they are more specific for cosplay conventions/competitions, whereas "fiera del fumetto" is generally used for everything related to comics, videogames, pop culture, and cosplays.

This helps, thank you. What do you think people usually call them when talking to friends? Organizers might not use the same term as visitors.

@SoBiT Often I hear them called by their actual name, like "Romics" (which is a comic convention based in Rome) or "Lucca comics" (in Lucca, Tuscany), but "fiera del fumetto" is also used in informal talks.

I agree with @tino: I would use the convention name when I am referring to a specific comic convention. Otherwise, I would use fiera del fumetto, including in the case I do not want to say to which comic convention I have been.
